# What do the village specific points do?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

In Monster Hunter Generations, there are several main villages. Doing quests for the villagers in each one will reward you with points for that specific village. I've earned a decent number of these points, but the game hasn't really explained what they actually do.

Comment: so far I've noticed after reaching certain number of points you get <village name> ticket, which uses are... i don't know.

Comment: @Rapitor They're for making weapons and armor, the same as with any other ticket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've seen while playing reaching certain levels of points will reward you with village specific tickets for crafting, new village requests, and new hunter arts.

The hunter arts are specific to each village as you can see from the awards screen on your guild card (there are awards for obtaining village specific arts). Can't say which arts are tied to which village though.